# Web proxy vs requests to Google Realtime Database

Tags: ios, google-api, fiddler, charles-proxy, webproxy

I have an iOS app which uses Google Realtime Database to store some user data there.

How secure are requests to Google Realtime Database?

I mean, is it possible to put the traffic from my app to Google servers into a web proxy like Charles or Fiddler, and decrypt that user data being sent?